# need understanding following code?

Tags: jquery

Could someone explain to me how the following code works? I've spent a bit of time trying to understand it, but it's beyond me. This is my code:

```
$('.acc_trigger').removeClass('active').next().slideUp(); 

$(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideDown();
```

The JSFiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kjHUv/7/).
**Edit**
I think so i understand it first it will hide all and show the current one thats selected thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.acc_trigger').removeClass('active').next().slideUp();
```

The first part selects all elements with the class `acc_trigger`. The second part removes the class `active` on those elements. The third part changes the selector to the next sibling of the selected element, and the fourth part does a slide up animation on that newly selected element.

```
$(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideDown();
```

This is roughly the same thing except it uses the current element, most likely from an event, and instead of merely removing the class it toggles it, which will add it if it's not there and remove it if it is.

Comment: @xeon6  when it $('.acc_trigger').removeClass('active') then it will select dom elements that early have the active class .

Comment: No. `$(".acc_trigger")` selects the elements iwth the class `acc_trigger`. It will then remove the class `active` on all those elements if they have it. If not, nothing happens.

Comment: when it removes class on that removing class  element then next and slideup will apply ?

Comment: Slide up will apply to the next sibling of the initial selector. For example, if you have code like this `<p>foo</p><div>bar</div>` and you do `$("p").next()` you will get the `div` element because it's the next sibling.

Answer (score 2):

This is simple jQuery method calls, nothing fancy. I suggest starting here:

http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page

and reading about each method until you have a better understanding of the whole picture.

```
$('.acc_trigger').removeClass('active').next().slideUp();
```

This removes a css class, and then hides the next control in the dom by doing the slideup animation.

```
$(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideDown();
```

This is adding a css class to the current selection, and then showing the next dom element with the slidedown animation.

Comment: @sawyer when it $('.acc_trigger').removeClass('active') then it will select dom elements that early have the active class

Comment: @Hira I'm not sure what you mean. the `removeClass` call is seperate from the selector, and acts upon the selected items. It is not selecting items that have the `active` css class.